# Identifying String format for a Color string

Tags: string, colors, format

given a string, I need to test if the string is in the following format [000,000,000,000] where 0 represents any number.  However each of the 4 numbers could be 1,2 or 3 digits.  If an error is detected, I need to throw a NumberFormatException and convert it to a FormatException.  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good - go for it!

Comment: I'm unsure how to do so

Comment: Start from the beginning, finish at the end, and if you're stuck in the middle - come here and we'll help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to check if it matches a regular expression. Something like this would do the trick:

`\[[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3}\]`

or this if you want a condensed version:

`\[([0-9]{1,3},){3}[0-9]{1,3}\]`

You didn't specify a language (I'd guess it's Java?), but they all have some regex functionality. Throwing the exception should be pretty simple for you, so I won't go into that...